# Function behaves differently if run in Unit Test vs. Console Application

Tags: c#, unit-testing

We're using an old third-party library. The library is a DLL that was compiled from C long ago. When I run a specific function from a unit test, I get the proper output. When I run the exact same code - byte-for-byte compared - in a console application instead or any form of runtime, I instead get invalid output. I have no idea what's going on. I can't provide the third-party library, but I can provide the code that we're running to make this happen, and the code is very minimal.

In the class library project that loads in the DLL and runs a function:

```
public class HFSAPI
{
    [DllImport("C:\\MCRIF32\\HFSWSAPI.dll")]
    static extern void GetMCRDataA(String instructions, StringBuilder result);

    public string GetData(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(new String(' ', 10000000));
        GetMCRDataA(input, output);
        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetBPart1AndCostCenters()
    {
        HFSAPI test = new HFSAPI();
        String input = File.ReadAllText("C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\XMLFile1.xml");
        String result = test.GetData(input);
        File.WriteAllText("Output.txt", result);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
    }
}
```

My console application, in an attempt to function, simply loads in the unit test and runs it as follows:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unitTest = new UnitTest1();
        unitTest.GetBPart1AndCostCenters();
        var result = File.ReadAllText("Output.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

I have no idea how this isn't working. I'm starting to think this is a compiler-level issue of some form or another. In the unit test, if I run or debug it, I get the right output - either way. In any form of a console application, if I run any of the code, EVEN BY DIRECTLY INVOKING THE UNIT TEST ITSELF, I get the invalid input. As noted in the code above, all paths are absolute, so it's not like they're using different inputs or anything.

For the sake of completeness, here's the XML file that's being loaded in with instructions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<instructions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <files>
        <file type="2552-10" instruction="Batch">C:\absolute\path\to\041331_12312016.mcrx</file>
    </files>
    <instruction name="Batch">
        <read id="worksheetsex">
        </read>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
```

Anybody have any leads as to why this behavior is happening, and how I can fix it? I can't just keep running the unit test to get the right output for the next step constantly. That's not feasible. Is there some flag that's being set or something?

Edit for clarification: The output when run through a unit test is an XML string with a length of over 368,000 characters. This is the correct and expected output. When run through a console application, it's 637 characters long. That gives you an idea of what kind of orders of magnitude it's off.

Comment: Old code can have odd requirements. A notorious example is the (t)rusty Office COM interop. For some reason it requiresa interactive session. As of Vista, Services no longer get interactive sessions. Wich becomes a issue for any Service and anythign running as a Service (WebServers) try to use it. This could be related.

Comment: I appreciate that, but why would it behave differently in a unit test than normal? I'm not sure what kind of flags are being set in the environment. I think my boss is looking into finding a workaround, like a different system for getting the data, but at the same time, I'd like to know what's going on here.

Comment: Just because it is a DLL does not mean it is designed for work with anything but WindowsForms or maybe the VCL Display Technology. As you said, it is some ages old C code. All we will be able to do is throw out a lot of theories. Try testing it with a bunch of Display technologies. With a pattern we might be able to do more then guesswork at where the issues is comming from.

Comment: It works in Windows Form! Thank you for that! Still, any idea what kind of environment flag was being set that would change that? I'm wondering more out of curiosity now, if this hadn't worked.

Comment: Put the [STAThread] attribute on Main() and try again.

Comment: Hans, thank you so much for that! That was the exact fix. If you want to post this as a solution, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Hans is a genius! Old thread, but I had to say it. I was trying to use the same library, and I discovered that if I called it from a VB script it worked as expected, but calling it from a C# console application returned a different result. I added the [STAThread] attribute to the Main method of the console application and it worked as expected